# First substring after X in Python

Tags: python, python-re

What would be an efficient way to find/extract the first *target* substring after another *control* substring in Python? For example:

```
'this is a string'
'this is a short string'
'this is a short but nice string'
```

In this example, **a** is the control the algorithm should find/extract the target **string** that appears after. Of course, both *control* and *target* can be different substrings, sometimes appearing imediately one after another and sometimes with in-between substrings. Some `re` function?

Comment: So you want to extract what is after `'a'`?

Comment: Let's say I have a three-column data frame, with Text, Control, and Target. I need to find the Target that is the first to appear after Control. There could be more than one Target but I need to extract only the first one + that Target does not need to be immediately after the Control. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of `target` with the following:

```py
indexOfControl = example.find(control)
if indexOfControl != -1
   indexOfTarget = example.find(target, indexOfControl+1)
```

Comment: This looks quite useful. Then I only need to grab a substring from the `indexOfTarget`. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, `re` is great for this.

```py
import re

def first_substring_after(text, control, target):
    match = re.search(f"(.*?){control}(.*?){target}(.*)", text)
    return (" ".join(g.strip() for g in match.groups())).strip() if match else None

def test_first_substring_after():
    assert first_substring_after("this is a string", "a", "string") == "this is"
    assert first_substring_after("this is a short string", "a", "string") == "this is short"
    assert first_substring_after("this is a short but nice string", "a", "string") == "this is short but nice"
    assert first_substring_after("this is a short but nice string and another string", "a", "string") == "this is short but nice and another string"
```

Comment: This does not locate the target but the string after the control.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Might help to give an example of the output you are looking for?

Comment: Output could, for example, look like this: 
`outputExamples = ['this is', 'this is short', 'this is short but nice']` 
etc.

Comment: Also, in a case like this: `examples = ['this is a short but nice string and another string']` 
the result should be: 
`outputExamples = ['this is short but nice and another string']`

Comment: (Updated) OK, this seems to work. Bit inelegant with all the stripping, but tests pass.